# Git first push: Sending email and Cannot allocate memory

Tags: git, memory-management, git-push

I am trying to use a git push for the first time on my git repository for a specific project and I am getting this error:

```
remote: Sending mail...
remote: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.12.0/lib/git_commit_notifier/emailer.rb:159:in `popen': Cannot allocate memory - /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

Anybody faced this error and if so, how could this be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might be a clue of some kind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419740/causes-for-enomem-from-popen

Comment: Thank you @JohnZwinck, but I don't thing this cqan help: It is a post-receave git script that makes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening on the remote site (i.e. where you are pushing to) in a hook that executes upon your push. Seemingly the server runs out of memory.

You cannot do much about it locally, but you need to contact the owner of the remote.

Comment: then: can you send mail in general? where does that hook come from? does it work for other repos? are you under memory pressure? what do kernel/application logs tell?

Comment: Probably, the first commit email was too big, I disabled the email notofication on the server side for the first commit and now everything works well.